# How to call multiple APIs using axios.all() when one of the endpoints is not working?

Tags: node.js, react-native

Suppose I have an array on endpoints and I want to call them using axios.all() but one of the endpoint is down or not working how to get data only from the working endpoints

```
 const res = await axios.all(BPPs.map(BPPs => axios.get(BPPs)));

  console.log(res);
    const cataLouge = res.map(e => {
      return e.data;
    });
    console.log(cataLouge);
```

this is my functions which is calling all the endpoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`axios.all()` has [been deprecated](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042). Instead, use Promise.all() or Promise.allSettled().

There is no way with `axios.all()` to get other responses if one of the call fails.